# How much slow are the cursors in Sybase

Tags: database, stored-procedures, cursor, sybase

I have heard that cursors are very slow in Sybase, it is even said that we should avoid cursors. Can somebody tell how slow are the cursors in Sybase. Are read only cursors fine, or they are also very slow, and is it acceptable to use cursors altogether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20020_1251/html/databases/databases537.htm

here is your answer with example.... Sample execution times against a 5000-row table

```
Procedure             | Access method                   | Time  
---------------------------------------------------------------------
increase_price        | Uses three table scans          | 28 seconds  
increase_price_cursor | Uses cursor, single table scan  |125 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for the data, are the read-only cursors also this much slow in Sybase

Comment: There are two cursor modes: read-only and update. As the names suggest, read-only cursors can only display data from a select statement; update cursors can be used to perform positioned updates and deletes. But any cursor will slow down database read-only is little fast that update as is does not perform modification on database.

Comment: Might be - as the locking is avoided, the read-only cursors may be faster

Comment: yes it it is fast than update but it depends how big your data is if your table contains millions of records it might slow otherwise will work fine..

Answer (score 1):

I think the statement is incomplete. The actual claim might be

Cursors are slower than SET-BASED operations/sql statements.

This is true for all databases, not just Sybase. And as a general rule, you must try (hard) and use SQL and set based operations instead of cursors and looping through records, as and when possible.